# What are the advantages of using Jenkins over Hudson?

Tags: jenkins, software-recommendation, hudson

[Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) is a fork of [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).

What are the benefits/advantages of using Jenkins over Hudson for a small private business?

Comment: For reference, there is a [similar question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973981/how-to-choose-between-hudson-and-jenkins) (although probably outdated now).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Number of commits.

Jenkins is a fork of Hudson (as commented [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/7/why-has-hudson-been-renamed-to-jenkins)) but has a more active development, Hudson's [last commit](http://git.eclipse.org/c/hudson/org.eclipse.hudson.core.git/log/) is quite old. And look at Hudson's [open bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&component=&product=Hudson&query_format=advanced)

Answer (score 6):

In short: the community. I developed a Jenkins plugin recently, and supporting Hudson did not even cross my mind (Jenkins has waaay more plugins).

Comment: This is pretty much the answer given by Jenkins on [their wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=53608972).

Comment: Seems like a similar answer to a question like "why use Drupal instead of WP" ...

Answer (score 3):

**Jenkins is better [Because](https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=53608972)**

- most users moving on to Jenkins, as well as other adoption metrics indicating clear shift in the userbase.
- the Hudson team has moved to develop Jenkins. So you can trust our expertise and the the passion to keep pushing the software forward.
- a large number of plugin authors have chosen to support their plugins on Jenkins. So you can expect bug fixes and new improvements to them from Jenkins.
- we'll make incremental iterative improvements to the code.
- the community supports us.
- well maintained documents. (Credits: [Martin Lee](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/8/martin-lee))

**Few more noticeable points are (from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973981/how-to-choose-between-hudson-and-jenkins))**

- Hudson/Jenkins is the product of a single genius intellect - [Kohsuke Kawaguchi](http://kohsuke.org/). Because of that, it's consistent, coherent, and rock solid. (By [Jonik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56285/jonik))
- Oracle now owns hudson and Jenkins is open-source. Both are MIT Licensed. Describing one as open-source and the other as other-than-open-source is misleading. They're free software (By [pb2q](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275567/pb2q))
- Hudson/Jenkins is all about the plugins. Plugin developers have moved to Jenkins and so should we, the users. (By [Tim Fulmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752693/tim-fulmer))